# Why do St. Croix and Angaur of Virgin Islands have same FIPS code?

Tags: geojson, united-states, fips

Could any one help me answer this. 
I am a non US citizen and working with d3js(geojson). I came across two locations in Virgin Islands which share the same FIPS code - St. Croix and Angaur have FIPS code 78010. I am looking for some sort of explanation around this.

I couldn't find any answer on the web.

Comment: Don't see Angaur only St Croix https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/codes/files/st78_vi_cou.txt

Comment: Like Mkennedy says, the bad typo of fips code included Angaur in VI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [National Association of Broadcaster's Engineering Handbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=K9N1TVhf82YC&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=fips+palau+angaur&source=bl&ots=RszfeGf3oz&sig=SP7Br-oBUtfUJ6UXv6bNKBl7Y3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic6cCPqdzUAhVH0WMKHamKCUsQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=fips%20palau%20angaur&f=false):

Table 1.18-3 lists the country code for Palau as "70". The administrative area code for Angaur is "010", in Table 1.18-4. So a typo on the country number.

The other Palau administrative districts probably aren't included because the original data request was for the 50 states plus American Samoa, Guam, Puerto Rico, and the US Virgin Islands AKA the current territories and they were likely requested via a list of country/state/territory. Angaur got included because of the bad FIPS number.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy, this answers my question. I probably got the us.json  file with one wrong entry.